# Add value to Drop Down list when exception occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP .NET(4.0) web app. The web app has a form view that contains a drop down list. The drop down list is populated like so:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStaff" runat="server" 
   DataSourceID="StaffDatasource" DataTextField="StaffName" 
   DataValueField="StaffName" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
   SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Staff") %>' >
   <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="StaffDatasource" runat="server" 
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
   SelectCommand="*****">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The staff list is constantly changing so the issue is that SelectedValue throws an error because that staff member does not exist anymore.

I know you can check if the item exists in the list and catch the exception. What I would like to know is if there is a way to display the "non-existing" staff member in the drop down list if they do not exists? Although the name is not listed the staff name is stored with the record. The reason I want to do this is because the users will need to see who was assigned to that record even if they are not there anymore.

EDIT: More details

This how the users would like for it to work.

- Missing staff name (This will be selected if not listed and should only show for that record)
- Null
- Adam
- Abigail
- Brandon
- .....

If it's possible to do this then I can let them know and I'll have it select null when the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the member is not on the list he isn't present. Why would you want that behaviour? Does the user need old members?

You could create a list with all members old and new ones - but you will have to code the list not declaring. You cannot do it with source controls. You can simply provide a collection to use as the datasource.

Hope this helped a bit.

Comment: I added more detail. The company needs to keep history of who was assigned to that record, even if they are not present. I would like to turn it into a textbox so that they can type in the staff member name instead, but they really like the drop down list because it's convenient.

Comment: Okay I see - I would create the list - with a combination of Query in the codebehind - make a collection of users and make that as the datasource. Or maybe you should create two tables one for old members and one for new members and join them. And use the resulting rows then you binding would work. You should just use selectedIndex = -1 instead don't select null IMO.